# How do I pass a plus sign in input parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I pass an email address with a plus sign in my input parameter?

Username Value is "johnsmith+1@gmail.com"

http://domain.com/page1.aspx?username=johnsmith+1@gmail.com

?
It does not seem to work?

Comment: You should *always* URLEncode, for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Server.UrlEncode method if you can:

Codebehind:

```
string email = "johnsmith+1@gmail.com"
lnkThingy.NavigateUrl = "http://www.website.com/Page1.aspx?email=" + Server.UrlEncode(email);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use HttpUtility.UrlEncode method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In URLs, a plus sign is generally used as a placeholder for a space.  "domain.com" is probably translating it back to a space before it's processing that page.

You need to URL escape to plus:

```
 http://domain.com/page1.aspx?username=johnsmith%2b1@gmail.com
```

'+' == ascii 43 == 0x2B.   Url escaping is "percent-sign; hex value of character"

Answer (score 1):

johnsmith%2b1%40gmail.com

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS G:\Users\Max> [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Web")

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v2.0.50727     G:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll


PS G:\Users\Max> [web.httputility]::UrlEncode("johnsmith+1@gmail.com")
johnsmith%2b1%40gmail.com
PS G:\Users\Max>
```

Comment: Never would have thought to use PowerShell to demonstrate this. Cool :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) for this. It escapes all characters that may mean something else when passed inside an url. Your e-mail address comes out like this:

```
johnsmith%2b1%40gmail.com
```

Both the `+` and the `@` are escaped using their hexadecimal representation, preceded by a `%`. You can check this for yourself [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) (`www.asciitable.com`).

Answer (score 0):

Plus(+) sign has a semantic meaning in the query string. It is used to represent a space.Most server side scripts would decode the query parameters before using them, so that a + gets properly 
converted to a space.

So before sending value in query string convert + symbol with %2B and then send. Below is the sample code.

```
protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string signature="f1wRcMvJJ2YjLjc8dc+7ykY9szg=&kanna";
    signature = signature.Replace("+", "%2B");
    Response.Redirect("Encode-Decode-QueryString.aspx?sign=" +     Server.UrlEncode(signature));
}
```

You can refer the below link for more details

http://www.dotnetpickles.com/2014/02/aspnet-how-to-pass-plus-in-query-string.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign is often decoded by .NET into a space character before you have a chance to call the UrlDecode method.  I use the following string extension methods to correct the issue and provide better access and control over querystring parameters.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Character Encodes a (string).  Specifically used for Querystring parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    /// <param name="String"></param>
    /// <returns>string</returns>
    public static string EncodeForQueryString(this string String)
    {
        String = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String);
        return String;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Character Decodes a (string).  Specifically used for Querystring parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>The plus sign causes issues when using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDeEncode.  The plus sign is often decoded before it reaches this method.  This method will replace any extra + with %2b before attempting to decode</remarks>
    /// <param name="String"></param>
    /// <returns>string</returns>
    public static string DecodeForQueryString(this string String)
    {
        String = String.Replace("+", "%2b");
        String = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(String);
        return String;
    }
```

To create the encoded string for your querystring parameter value:

```
string myUrl = "myPage.htm?q=" + "Saving+Silverman".ToString().EncodeForQueryString();
```

To fetch and decode the querystring parameter value:

```
string myDecodedString = Request.Params["q"].DecodeForQueryString();
```