# Encoding Decoding not working proper in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Encoding String using HttpUtility.UrlEncode. Here is conversation

```
mTcNKNVhy7+4FH+tDN4WGQ==    >>  mTcNKNVhy7%2b4FH%2btDN4WGQ%3d%3d
```

Now I am decoding same thing in using HttpUtility.UrlDecode. Here is output

```
mTcNKNVhy7%2b4FH%2btDN4WGQ%3d%3d     >> mTcNKNVhy7 4FH tDN4WGQ==
```

While Decoding `%2b` is converting to space instead of `+`

I also tried Server.URLecode/Decode, but no success.

Comment: This - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25918990/477420 ?